# Filter a PivotChart with Dates

Tags: excel, ms-access, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I'm trying to introduce a Chart with a PivotChart on Excel, but the data is in an Access Database.

I show my Chart perfectly, something like that:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyYSl.png)

[Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ9sq.png)

But I want to display this same Chart with a Filter. A filter with a date field. And this field have to between a date.
This same chart but with data between a date.
  I try applying this filter but It doesn't work.

Can you help me?

And one thing more, Is it possible create a calculated field with the database and graph separate?

Answer (score 0):

A more interactive way to add a filter to a PivotChart is to `Insert a Slicer`.  To do this, Select your PivotTable > Select the Analyze tab on the Ribbon > Select Insert Slicer > Check Date field > Click Ok.

Below is a simple example showing my PivotChart filtered down to 3 dates.  Use the Ctrl/Shift keys to select multiple dates.

Hope this helps!

[image: CRUTER.com PivotChart PivotTable Slicer]